# Chrome extension rich notifications not showing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications

In my code, I want to be able to create notifications, but the following code is not working. I can't seem to find a tutorial anywhere and the API is making no sense to me. Here is my code, I appreciate all help. Thanks!

```
function notify(string) {
    chrome.notifications.create(string)
}
notify("Testing")
```

In my manifest:

```
"permissions": [ "unlimitedStorage", "tabs", "notifications"]
```

Comment: You're not passing in nearly enough to the create method. The documentation is actually pretty clear and concise. Did you look here? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#method-create

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not a Chrome developer.

According to the docs, the notifications.create method requires a few options to be supplied in an object, and the first parameter is an ID for the notification.

```
function notify(title, callback) {

    var options = {
        title: title,
        message: "Message goes here"
        type: "basic", // Which type of notification to display - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#type-TemplateType
        iconUrl: "someimage.jpg" // A URL to the sender's avatar, app icon, or a thumbnail for image notifications.
    };

    // The first argument is the ID, if left blank it'll be automatically generated.
    // The second argument is an object of options. More here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#type-NotificationOptions
    return chrome.notifications.create("", options, callback);

}

notify("Testing", function(notification){
    // Do whatever you want. Called after notification is created.
});
```

**Edit:** Guess all arguments are required then. Updated code above. This should work fine for a simple notification, but when you start doing anything advanced you should [read the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#method-create).

Comment: Uncaught Error: Invocation of form notifications.create(string, object) doesn't match definition notifications.create(string notificationId, object options, function callback)

Comment: Should be `chrome.notifications.create(options, callback);`

Comment: The notification doesn't show up. It appears to be sent (callback is called), but nothing is shown.

Answer (score 1):

**It seems the `iconUrl` was creating the issue**
use chrome.extension.getURL("/favicon-32x32.png")

```
function notify(title, callback) {
  var options = {
    title: title,
    message: "Message goes here",
    type: "basic", // Which type of notification to display - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#type-TemplateType
    iconUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("/favicon-32x32.png") // A URL to the sender's avatar, app icon, or a thumbnail for image notifications.
  };

  // The first argument is the ID, if left blank it'll be automatically generated.
  // The second argument is an object of options. More here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#type-NotificationOptions
  return chrome.notifications.create("demo", options, callback);
}
```